# Plot figures with different figure sizes within the same R Markdown Code Chunk

Tags: r-markdown

For building a report, I am using r-markdown and Knitr. Since I have to compute the same kind of plots, calculations and texts (like headings, paragraphs, etc.) for a changing number of realms and metrics, I want to use methods as much as possible, such that I don't have to repeat the same code chunks over and over for each new combination of realm and metric. Therefore I use the code chunk option `results='asis'` and generate markdown on the fly.

My problem is, that - within each combination of realm and metric - I would like to create one kind of plot with a bigger figure height and another kind of plot with a smaller figure height. Here is a minimal reproducible example (MRE). You can save it as an .Rmd-File and use Knitr within RStudio to generate this MRE-Report.

````
---
output: 
  word_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
operation_big_plot <- function(realm, metric){
  plot(1:10, 1:10, main=paste0(realm, " - ", metric, " - big plot"))
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
operation_small_plot_1 <- function(realm, metric){
  plot(1:10, 1:10, main=paste0(realm, " - ", metric, " - small plot 1"))
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
operation_small_plot_2 <- function(realm, metric){
  plot(1:10, 1:10, main=paste0(realm, " - ", metric, " - small plot 2"))
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
realm_plots <- function(realm){
  cat("# ", realm, "\n")
  dynamic_set_of_metrics <- c("metric 1", "metric 2", "metric 3")
  for(metric in dynamic_set_of_metrics){
    cat("## ", metric, "\n")
    operation_big_plot(realm, metric)
    operation_small_plot_1(realm, metric)
    operation_small_plot_2(realm, metric)
    cat("\n\n")
  }
  cat("\\newpage")
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
realm_plots("realm 1")
realm_plots("realm 2")
realm_plots("realm 3")
```
````

So the `operation_big_plot` code part should be plotted with a bigger figure height and the `operation_small_plot_1` and `operation_small_plot_2` should be plotted with a smaller figure height.

So far, I did not achieve this. I tried already to set the code chunk option `fig.height` for the different code chunk blocks, however, that did not work. For each figure, the figure.height of the most outer block (the last one in the above example) seems to get used.

I am thankful for any tips and recommendations.